# Using Reactive UI with another MVVM framework

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui

I am using MvvmCross and finding this very productive, however I have just discovered ReactiveUI and the functional reactive style is very appealing.

I've tried using ReactiveCommand for some basic examples, but I cannot make use of some of the very useful extension methods such as ObservableAsPropertyHelper and ToProperty without having ReactiveObject as my base class. (I already have one from mvx)

So my question is: **What are the restrictions to using ReactiveUI if I cannot inherit from ReactiveObject as a base class for my ViewModels?**

I've seen ReactiveUI described as a buffet library (i.e. take the bits you like) but it seems that ReactiveObject is quite fundamental to it's use. Has anyone else got any experience of this?

Both libraries are awesome, please don't make me choose! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ToProperty` is afaik the only method that requires `ReactiveObject`, the other classes / methods will work fine with MvvmCross